# How to upload to a launchpad team PPA?

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad, dput

I have built and signed a package which I now wish to upload to my launchpad team with `dput`, but every time that I try to upload it I get this email:

```
Rejected:
Source/binary (i.e. mixed) uploads are not allowed.



===

If you don't understand why your files were rejected please send an email
to launchpad-users@lists.launchpad.net for help (requires membership).

--
https://launchpad.net/~*****/+archive/ubuntu/*****
You are receiving this email because you are the uploader of the above
PPA package.
```

I have tried to configure my `.dput.cf` file (the config file for `dput`) with:

```
[secretiveppc]
fqdn = ppa.launchpad.net
method = ftp
incoming = ~*****/+archive/ubuntu/*****
login = *****
allow_unsigned_uploads = 0
```

But it still is not letting me upload my `.changes` file with:

```
dput -ppa:*****/***** anti-sr_1.0-1~trusty_amd64.changes
```

To my launchpad team PPA, I am guessing that this is because only team members are allowed to upload packages to the team's PPA, but I am a member of the team, so how do I make sure it knows that? Is there some config file where I have to put my username and password or something? Or...? (I have replaced any information I do not wish to provide with `*****`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you received an email with `Approved` or `Rejected`, then you've uploaded your package successfully.

But, in this case, after the upload the package was rejected with the message `Source/binary (i.e. mixed) uploads are not allowed`.

I.e., you need to build a source package only.

In order to achieve that, create your package with `debuild -S`.